# Overcoming ? row ? or ? memory ? issue in R studio compiling a massive database

Tags: r, memory, rstudio, tableau-api, rbind

I have a large database which I wish to analyze in Tableau. However, files are organized by quarter overtime and are massive (10s of millions of rows each) and are sas7bdat files. I am attempting to stack these files so that they can be analyzed all at once and linked with other files in tableau (Tableau has no stacking function). I am using a MAC desktop (as this is what is provided by my employer)

Here is my mock code

```
library(haven)

#Pull in sas7bdat files into R studio

2001q1<- read_sas("Year 2001 quarter 1", NULL)

2001q2<- read_sas("Year 2001 quarter 2", NULL)

# and so on until

2018q4 <- read_sas("Year 2018 quarter 4", NULL)

#Combine rows 

2001_2018_ALL <-rbind(2001q1, 2001q2...2018q4)

#Write file

write_sas(2001_2018_ALL, "2001_2018_ALL")
```

The issue is that at the rbind step I get the following error:

> Error in if (n > 0) c(NA_integer_, -n) else integer() :    missing
>   value where TRUE/FALSE needed

In addition: Warning messages:

> 1: In Make.row.names(nmi, ri, ni, nrow) :   NAs introduced by coercion
>   to integer range 2: In nrow + ni : NAs produced by integer overflow

I know there isn't a flaw in the code per se as if I take smaller chunks (say 2001-2003 or 2004-2006) this is successful. However, if I try to combine more files (in the hundreds of millions of rows) I get that error.

Any thoughts as to why this is happening? or alternative ways to stack the data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean when you say Tableau doesn't have a stacking function? You can stack/union datasets when importing the data.

Comment: As much as I love R it seems like you can avoid using R here and just use a union from within Tableau: https://community.tableau.com/thread/288362  the logic in that link applies just as equally to importing .sas7bdat files

Comment: Thanks Dason- I'm new to tableau entirely so my first inquiry to whether I could stack datasets came back with a bunch of responses saying I couldnt. Apparently I was using the wrong word because union seems to work just fine from what I'm reading / you linked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem.  I'm glad you included your actual goal at the beginning or this might have turned into a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Actually, according to Tableau's website, SAS files can't be unioned. https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/union.htm

Comment: Huh. Well that sucks.  I guess you could avoid the rbind and just write a loop to convert the sas7bat to csv though and then union those from within tableau.